# MySql self join optimizing query

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to find out some junk data from my database in which Parent is deleted but child is not deleted(one level only). To explain the situation I am providing some sample data.

Query to create sample table

```
CREATE TABLE  `parentchild` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_parentchild_Self` (`parentid`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_parentchild_Self` FOREIGN KEY (`parentid`) REFERENCES `parentchild` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

After inserting some dummy data the table looks like

```
id  parentid    Name     IsDeleted
1               Fruits       1
2     1         Mango        0
3     1         Apple        0
4               Car          0
5     4         Baleno       0
6     4         Santro       0
7               Animals      0
8     7         Dog          0
9     7         Cat          0
```

Now the query which I have formed to find out the first level children's is

```
SELECT t2.Name AS Name, t1.Name AS ParentName FROM parentchild t1
INNER JOIN parentchild t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ParentID
WHERE t1.IsDeleted=1 AND t2.IsDeleted=0;
```

The output which I got from this query seems to be fine

```
Name    ParentName
Mango   Fruits
Apple   Fruits
```

But my concern is about the performance as its explain output is not satisfactory.

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys           key                 key_len     ref                 rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE        t1                ALL     PRIMARY                                                                      8       12.50      Using where
1   SIMPLE        t2                ref     FK_parentchild_Self     FK_parentchild_Self     5       test1.t1.id 2        2       12.50      Using where
```

Can anyone please let me know the correct indexes or a better query to get this optimized?

I have tried adding indexes on *Index(id,IsDeleted)* , *Index(parentid,IsDeleted)* and *Index(id, parentid, IsDeleted)* but none works to optimize the scanning.

In my staging environment this data is around 1 lac rows and it is scanning all the rows to find out 18 records whose parent is deleted but they are not. [Here](https://ibb.co/Zfq6Wy8) is the explain of my staging environment. In my production environment there are million of rows, so I cannot run this query on huge data.

Answer (score -1):

One indexing strategy would use this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON parentchild (ParentID, IsDeleted, Name);
```

This would speed up the lookup against `parentchild`, going from left to right in the join process.  The other possible strategy would be:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON parentchild (ID, IsDeleted, Name);
```

This might speed up the join in the other direction, should MySQL decides to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't see much difference after adding these indexes. It is still scanning 8 rows for table t1. Please have a look at explain https://ibb.co/7g5GBdz

Comment: _8 rows_ ?  If your table only has 8 rows, then MySQL may not choose to use _any_ index.  Statistics are fairly meaningless on a table that small.  Just run your query without indices and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, this is a sample table. I got your point, Let me run the query on my Staging environment which has around 1 lac rows and will share the stats.

Comment: Please see the explain result after executing query on a table having 1,13,935 records. First one is with default indexes https://ibb.co/Zfq6Wy8 and the second is after applying the indexes suggested by you https://ibb.co/BwLT3rM . The result is still same.